# Are there better ways to prevent 'yield' when no block is passed in?

Tags: ruby, block, yield

I have a method that yields, which looks like:

```
def a_method(*params)
  # do something
  yield
  # do something else
end
```

I want this method to yield the block if a block is passed in; and if no block is passed in, the method should sliently skip the yield sentense without crashing with something like:

```
 no block given (yield) (LocalJumpError)
```

Of course, the most straightforward way is changing the method to:

```
def a_method(*params, &block)
  # do something
  yield if block
  # do something else
end
```

But aren't there prettier ways?

Answer (score 73, accepted):

Yes! :)

```
def a_method(*params)
  # ...
  yield if block_given?
  # ...
end
```

Comment: Note that it's also faster than capturing a block (with `&block`).

Comment: I freaking always forget the name of `block_given?`